# Join a select group of child tables to one parent tables

Tags: postgresql

I have 4 postgres tables:

- Fruit with attribute freshness (int) that goes to 1 to 5 and a serial id pk
- Banana with curvature  (int) that goes from 0 to 360 and a serial id pk that is both foreign key to fruit and bananas primary key
- Apple with color as text and the same fk pk id
- pineapple with weight as int and the same fk id as the other two

Heres an example for a fruit (you can imagine the others, they are very similar):

```
CREATE TABLE apple
(
    color text,
    id int primary key references fruit(id)
)
```

Now would like to query for both freshness, curvature and color for all bananas and apples.

Heres what I've tried:

```
select * from fruit
natural full join apple
natural full join banana;
```

[image]

Unfortunately, it also returns all the pineapples (bottom 2). But if I do a regular join, it returns nothing at all (since both joins filter out each others rows).

So how can I return only apples and bananas without the pinapples  in a  single query?

Comment: How about `SELECT ... FROM fruit LEFT JOIN apple ON fruit.id = apple.id LEFT JOIN banana ON ... WHERE color IS NOT NULL AND curvature IS NOT NULL`. That will get all fruit rows, joined on both apple and banana rows, and then filter out the fruit rows where both color and curvature are NULL (i.e. any rows that did not match any in those 2 tables).

Comment: because its a lot more than 2 tables in my real problem. And those attributes make actually be null

Comment: Ok. Number of tables is irrelevant I think, because you need to join on them all regardless right? You can change the filter then to the actual ids: `WHERE apple.id IS NULL AND banana.id IS NULL` etc. Any row where it didn't match the explicitly joined tables will be removed. There may be better ways but this is what comes to mind for me.

Comment: that sounds better. Its not very DRY but I think it will work fine. Thanks.